# Redirect a Website to a local folder Using window.location.href() not working

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, window.location

`developer.android` is not available in my country, so I wrote a greasemonkey script to redirect my google search to local android doc in my sdk folder.

But it doesn't work.i

It seems that `window.location.href` cannot 
work on local addresses.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Android Doc Redirect
// @namespace   me
// @author      me
// @description Redirect developer.android.com to local Documention
// @include     *http://developer.android.com/*
// @match        http://developer.android.com/*
// @version     1.0
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  var str = "http://developer.android.com/";
  var str2 = "file:///home/user/android-sdk-linux/docs/";
//   var str2 = "http://google.com";
  if(url.startsWith(str))
    {
      url = url.replace(str, str2);
      window.location.href = url;
    }
}())
```

Comment: the browser blocks it for security reasons. depending on the browser you are using you can disable this security measure

Comment: I would suggest you to setup a little local http server, maybe with Lighttpd which is very fast and lightweight or NGINX, which works very well when serving static files (like your docs) and then add a line to your hosts file to point developer.android.com to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @atmd , assume that i am using firefox.can you help me?

Comment: @Clever I've added an answer with some plugins that can do it (but a local server is a better approach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly, setting up a local server is the best way to go, as it avoid security issues with `file://` extentions in browsers. I'd suggest using [node](https://nodejs.org/) with a simple http server.

(or using something like [static serve](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static))

If you really want to disable the security warning you have, there is a [localLink plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/locallink/) that will do it, or you can use [no script](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/). There are also few other solutions [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work) about disabling the security flag/limit.